# Apache zeppelin tutorial, error "sql interpreter not found"

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

In the "*Zeppelin tutorial*" notebook, I can't use the **%sql interpreter**. It will output "`sql interpreter not found`". But the spark commands work fine, as well as `%md` and `%sh`.

Here's the log :

> ERROR [2015-10-20 10:13:35,045] ({qtp885851948-51} NotebookServer.java[runParagraph]:615) - Exception from run
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sql interpreter not found
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.NoteInterpreterLoader.get(NoteInterpreterLoader.java:148)
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Note.run(Note.java:282)
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.runParagraph(NotebookServer.java:613)
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.onMessage(NotebookServer.java:126)
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookSocket.onMessage(NotebookSocket.java:56)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:835)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. The problem was that the spark interpreter was deselected. At the top of the tutorial page, open the gear icon and make sure "spark %spark..." is *blue* and click save.

The UI is a bit confusing here. All interpreters are selected (blue) by default. You just have to click "save"

Comment: Rather confusing fact about the Zeppelin tutorial. The first thing you see is: "Bind interpreter for this note. Click to Bind/Unbind interpreter. Drag and drop to reorder interpreters. 
The first interpreter on the list becomes default. To create/remove interpreters, go to Interpreter menu." So I kind of naturally clicked on the Spark interpreter - which then causes this problem...

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one following that logic :)

Comment: Terrible UX, I had identified that the Spark interpretter needed to be turned on, but until I read this I thought that was what I had just done, when in fact I turned it off! Thanks for saving me hours of head scratching.

Answer (score 4):

Just add %spark to the "Load Data Into Table"

```
%spark
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
```

after that replace `%sql` with `%spark.sql` in your queries.

It will work.

Also, ensure that Spark and md in the interpreters are selected(blue means selected) and click on save.