# Null Pointer Exception After Adding Dependency to Spark2 Interpreter

Tags: apache-spark, nullpointerexception, dependency-management, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to add this dependency to the spark 2 interpreter in zeppelin

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0

However, after adding the dependency, I get a null pointer exception when running any code.

[image: Null Pointer Exception Screenshot]

[image: Spark & Scala Version Screenshot]

[image: Adding Dependency]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text in a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), as these are not searchable. Paste the text itself. Then people can find it to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was defining a class in Scala. The methods to_date & date_format were being used inside the class but my import statements were outside the class. All I had to do was place the import statements inside the class brackets and it worked fine.

```
case class HelperClass(){
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

var fire_services_customDF = fire_servicesDF
var data=fire_servicesDF

def SetDatatypes() : Unit = {
    data=fire_services_customDF.withColumn("CallDateTmp",date_format(to_date(col("CallDate"), "MM/dd/yy"), "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("timestamp"))
}

def PrintSchema() : Unit= {
         data.printSchema
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add spark-sql, it is already in spark interpreter.

Comment: Im trying to run this command:
data=fire_services_customDF.withColumn("CallDateTmp",date_format(to_date(col("CallDate"), "MM/dd/yy"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).cast("timestamp")Getting this error:
<console>:37: error: not found: value date_format     data=fire_services_customDF.withColumn("CallDateTmp",date_format(to_date(col("CallDate"), "MM/dd/yy"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).cast("timestamp")

<console>:37: error: not found: value to_date
data=fire_services_customDF.withColumn("CallDateTmp",date_format(to_date(col("CallDate"), "MM/dd/yy"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).cast("timestamp")

Comment: date_format is the function of spark sql. You need to import them explicitly. This error is not due to the missing of spark sql jar

Answer (score 0):

Just add `%spark.sql` at the top of your notebook to provide an SQL environment

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/spark.html#overview

Comment: Getting this error now: <console>:2: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
%spark.sql

Comment: make sure the correct interpretors are selected (the wheel on the right hand side) https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567972/3213111